# PrimeFaces PickList component, how to get all target values to one InputText component?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I created xhtml page with one `inputText` and one `commandButton` component. When I clicked on button is displaying `overlayPanel` with `pickList` and one `commandButton` under list. I want to get all target values and put it into `inputText` (this component must be only one). Can you help me how to do it?

Below is xhtml code that I wrote for now:

```
<h:panelGrid id="displayPlayers" columns="3">
        <ui:repeat value="#{pickListBean.players.target}" var="player"> 
            <p:inputText id="input2" value="#{player.name}" />
        </ui:repeat> 
        <p:commandButton id="overPanBtn2" value="overPanBtn2" type="button" />
    </h:panelGrid>

    <p:overlayPanel id="chartPanel2" for="overPanBtn2" hideEffect="fade">
        <p:pickList id="pickList4" value="#{pickListBean.players}" var="player" itemLabel="#{player}" itemValue="#{player}" converter="playerConverter">
            <p:column style="width:75%;">  
                #{player.name}  
            </p:column>
            <p:column style="width:75%;">  
                #{player.number}  
            </p:column>
        </p:pickList>
        <p:commandButton id="playerSubmit4" value="Ok" update="displayPlayers" style="margin-top:5px" />
    </p:overlayPanel>
```

I will be grateful for help.

Comment: Can't understand why you need <ui:repeat> if you say "component must be only one". You would probably need <f:ajax event="transfer" listener="#{pickListBean.onTransfer}" execute="@this" render=":displayPlayers:input2" />. onTransfer method shoud calculate the string you need and make it available as a field for input tag.

Comment: I try without `ui:repeat` tag only with `<p:inputText id="input2" value="#{pickListBean.players.target}" />` but it don't work like I wish. I'll try with `f:ajax` tag.

Comment: So I need to delete `ui:repeat` tag, but where put `#{pickListBean.players.target}` ? And where in I need to add `f:ajax` tag?

Comment: The `f:ajax` has to go into the component which the event will be happened, for your case into `<pickList>` and `</pickList>`. The event you want to control is `transfer` as @skegg99 said. So create a `String` property in your backing bean in order to concat the selected players, for example `pickListBean.selectedPlayerNames`. When transfer happens into `pickList`, the listener will be called and here you have to assign the `pickListBean.players.target` values to your property. After that the panel will be updated with selected values. You don't need `ui:repeat`.

Comment: I can't make sense of your question. You have a component that inherently stores multiple values. You now want those multiple values to show up in a single component, that can hold only a single value, at the same time?

Comment: @skegg99 @XtremeBiker thank you very much for your answer. Can you give me any sample of `onTransfer` implementation? Im new in primefaces and this is my first task in this technology.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case it should be something like that, you only have to follow [the showcase example](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/picklist.jsf):

**XHTML**

```
<p:pickList id="pickList4" value="#{pickListBean.players}" var="player" itemLabel="#{player}" itemValue="#{player}" converter="playerConverter">
    <p:ajax event="transfer" listener="#{pickListBean.onTransfer}" update="msg" />
    <p:column style="width:75%;">  
            #{player.name}  
    </p:column>
    <p:column style="width:75%;">  
            #{player.number}  
    </p:column>
</p:pickList>
```

**BACKING BEAN**

```
String selectedPlayerNames;

//GETTER

public void onTransfer(TransferEvent event) {
    selectedPlayerNames = "";
    for (Player p : players.getTarget()){
        selectedPlayerNames += p.getName() + " ";
        }
}
```

Just call the event when transfer happens, and save the targeted values into the String. Then bind this String property to a `p:inputText`.